# R cannot be resolved to a variable cant clean project

Tags: java, android, xml, r.java-file

i already posted this question earlier this week, and still no luck and no answer to why im getting this.

i cant even clean the project because i get this error:

```
[2012-07-22 19:34:09 - CannonGame] W/ResourceType( 2808): Bad XML block: header size 116 or total size 0 is larger than data size 0
[2012-07-22 19:34:09 - CannonGame] C:\Users\Gaming\workspace\CannonGame\res\menu\main.xml:2: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'title' with value '@string/menu_settings').
```

someone tell me what to do! this is due tonight :/ ive been working on it all week and cant figure this out.

Comment: It seems something in your resource folder might be amiss;

I've had it give me strange messages when Windows has autogenerated files (thumbs.db) in my case.

Can you post what your folder structure looks like?

Comment: this class is twice a week, mon and wed, being due on monday i didnt have this problem the previous wed, so i emailed him. and as far as the folder structure: i got my res folder with 4 drawable-dpi/ldpi/mdpi/xhdp folders in them, layout folder with main.xml, menu folder with main.xml, values folder with dimens/strings/styles.xml, values-large folder with a dimens.xml, AndroidManifest.xml, a picture, proguard-project.txt and project.properties.

Comment: have you tried restarting eclipse? sometimes, this does a lot more good that it would seem.

Comment: 'No resource found that matches the given name (at 'title' with value '@string/menu_settings')' <--this is your key in solving your problem. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well for the answer to this post, the error is saying that whichever resource is being referenced on line 2 of `main.xml` can't be found with the `title` set to the value stored in `@string/menu_settings`.  Make sure that your references are correct.

As for Eclipse not being to resolve `R.java` into a variable, try to edit an XML file and then save the changes (even just a trailing whitespace at the end-of-file).  That will rebuild the references and recompile `R.java`.  If that doesn't work, go through all of the activities with this error and make sure that the `R.java` file that's being imported is `your.package.name.R`, rather than `android.R`.

Comment: so i got most of the errors taken care of, doing all that ^^ but one more error left, i keep getting "raw cannot be resolved or is not a field". how do i fix that?

Comment: Thanks for accepting the answer!  Maybe an upvote too? ;*  So it looks like this is another issue with `R.java`.  So you've gone through and made sure that the correct `R.java` file is being imported, `your.package.name.R`?  Did you also make sure to delete any `import` statements for `import android.R`?  If so, can you post the error from LogCat along with the relevant code for this problem?  If this is a problem referencing a resource from `raw` are you using the path `project/res/raw` instead of `project/raw`?